# Apache Jena in OSGi with Glassfish - ClassCastException

Tags: java, glassfish, osgi, jena

I am trying to create an OSGi based application which uses Apache Jena. I created a Jena bundle which inlines jena-core and its dependencies, and exports the relevant packages (com.hp.hpl.jena.*). The overall structure of the project is like this:

- Bundle containing Jena
- Bundles containing internal APIs
- Bundles implementing services defined in APIs
- WAR bundle which delivers these services RESTful web services

Loading the Jena bundle into the autodeploy folder in Glassfish works fine, and the log reports that it loads successfully. However, restarting the server with the bundle there causes the following exception:

```
INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-1] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8080]
INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-2] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8181]
INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [admin-listener] on host/port [0.0.0.0:4848]
INFO: WEB0171: Created virtual server [server]
INFO: WEB0171: Created virtual server [__asadmin]
SEVERE: Digester.getParser: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getFactory(Digester.java:526)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getParser(Digester.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.createContextDigester(ContextConfig.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.<clinit>(ContextConfig.java:187)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.EmbeddedWebContainer.createContext(EmbeddedWebContainer.java:217)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1832)
...
```

The Xerces parser inside my Jena bundle seems to be conflicting with Xerces in Glassfish. The POM file in my bundle looks like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <instructions>
      <Export-Package>com.hp.hpl.jena.*;org.apache.log4j;org.apache.log4j.*;org.slf4j;org.slf4j.*</Export-Package>
      <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=!runtime|provided;type=!pom;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
      <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
      <!-- fix the weird imports -->
      <Import-Package>!com.ibm.uvm.tools,!com.sun.*,!javax.jmdns,!javax.jms,!javax.jms.*,!javax.microedition.*,!com.google.gson,!org.apache.avalon.framework.*,!org.apache.commons.beanutils,!org.apache.commons.codec.binary,!org.apache.commons.collections,!org.apache.commons.digester,!org.apache.commons.digester.*,!org.apache.commons.jexl2,
      !org.apache.commons.jxpath,!org.apache.commons.jxpath.*,
      !org.apache.commons.vfs2,!org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider,!org.apache.log,!org.apache.xml.*,!org.apache.commons.jxpath
      !org.gjt.xpp,!org.jaxen,!org.jaxen.*,!org.relaxng.datatype,
      !org.w3c.dom.ls,!org.xmlpull.v1,!sun.io,!sun.misc,!org.gjt.xpp,*
      </Import-Package>
    </instructions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My understanding of OSGI was that only the packages I export are visible outside the bundle, and internal packages are safe from weird interactions like this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might accidentally provided your XML parser through META-INF/services? OSGi is really good in preventing these problems but it does require bundles that are designed for it. Looking at your bnd instructions it looks like this bundle was not designed with modularity in mind ...

Answer (score 0):

Apache Jena now includes an OSGi bundle [jena-osgi](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jena/jena-osgi/).